# Battery voltage drops when connected to a motor

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, batteries, dc-motor, quad-copter

I was recently working on a quadcopter so I bought a pair of coreless DC motor. My intention was to use an Arduino (DIP chip) to control the speed of the DC motor (rated 3.7 V) through a transistor.

But I have noticed that whenever I connect the motor to the battery (li-po 3.7 V) the voltage drops to about 2.8 V.
I have tried a 5 V boost converter but the voltage dropped to 2.8 V again.

Can anyone please tell me the reason.

Comment: What current is the motor drawing? What capacity of battery? What is the battery's max discharge rate? (either in amps or C) What state of charge as the battery?

Comment: Please provide a schematic of how you've connected things and where you're measuring the voltage.

Comment: motor is drawing 400mA of current.

Comment: battery has a discharge rate of about 15C. The battery has a capacity of 650mAH. The battery has enough charge(3.85V)

Comment: as of now I am not concerned about the micro-controller or the transistor.So there is no specific schematic. I had directly connected the motor to the battery and measured the voltage across the motor terminals.

Comment: [link](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/8pcs-DC3-7-4-2V-716-7-16-5MM-Micro-DIY-Helicopter-Coreless-DC-Motor-With/32428628283.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.138.8eoBr7 ) This to the link of the motor I am using

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the motor is trying to draw more current than the battery can supply.  The battery is like a squirt gun, and the motor needs a fire hose.

Comment: but the battery has a discharge rate of 15C.

Comment: motor requires about 400mA.and the battery has a capacity of 650mAH

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the [internal resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_resistance) of the battery. As soon as you draw current, the voltage at the battery's leads drops. Nevertheless, only 2.8 V sounds really little, maybe your battery is just drained.

**EDIT**: Come to think about it, a fully charged 15C battery can't easily be stressed to the point where it only outputs 2.8V. Especially not by such a puny motor. Are you sure the battery isn't just dead?

Comment: lets assume that its internal resistance.but when i connect the battery to a 5V dc dc boost converter and then connect the motor to it ,the voltage again drops to about 2.85V accross the motor

Comment: Care to tell us which dc-dc converter you are using?
BTW, a converter sounds like a really inefficient solution in this case. If you need more power, get a tougher motor and/or a bigger battery. The converter will easily bottleneck your power supply. Not to speak of the weight for an quadrocopter application...

Answer (score 0):

A Li-PO battery is sold and is stored at a partial 3.7V charge. It is 4.2V after a proper charge when it has full power. A proper charge is when it continues charging at 4.2V until its charging current drops to 1/10th or less.

My Li-PO batteries slowly drive my motors and not for long when they have a 3.7V storage charge.

A Li-PO battery must never be stored fully charged. If yours have been fully charged for longer than a few months then they are ruined and will produce low power.

A Li-PO also must never be discharged below about 3.0V or again it will be ruined.

Answer (score -3):

add a circuit like this between the Arduino chip and the motor. If I'm correct, the voltage will decrease due to the resistor, but the current should be the same as the battery, and will balance out. the concept is that if you put capacitors in parallel they all charge and create more current. You may need to experiment with the resistor a bit. also tell me if it doesn't work, I made this circuit quickly.[image]

Comment: You have the capictors in series between the battery and thr motor.  The motor will not run.  They might rotate briefly while the capacitors are charging, but that's it.  The motor will definitely not run.

Comment: The schematic is wrong. No current will flow except briefly when the circuit is switched on. The 100 Ohm resistor shown is also much too high a value. It will prevent any meaningful current from flowing to the motors (which should draw around 0.4 A). Even at 1 Ohm there will still be a very significant voltage drop.

Comment: Simulate this circuit in Spice. What warnings did you get for the capacitors?